# What docker commands does rancher run when I perform an upgrade

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rancher

I would like to understand what `rancher-compose` executes when I run the `up --upgrade` command. There does not seem to be an equivalent `docker-compose` command.

Comment: Do you mean "--no-deps", which can update the selected the services instead of all the services listed is compose. Example: docker-compose up -d --no-deps SERVICE1 SERVICE2

Comment: I'm currently trying to figure out what rancher is doing to docker containers when I run it with the up --upgrade command. There is an issue with our docker logging driver that only seems to happen after this rancher-compose command is run. Ideally I would like to reproduce this locally with docker-compose so I can attempt to debug the issue.